# Bitbucket Pipelines config for yii2. Need github token

Tags: yii2, composer-php, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use bitbucket pipelines for my project, and i use simple config:

```
image: phpunit/phpunit:5.0.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - composer --version
          - phpunit --version
          - composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
          - composer install
          - php init --env=Development --overwrite=All
```

But, at composer intall stage, i needs a github token, because yii2 is on github. 
So, how to run composer with token, using this config ?

Comment: create github account and generate token from github

Comment: @Nitin Ofcouse, but how to use it in docker container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to set some configuration for Composer. A link what command(s) to use: [API rate limit and OAuth tokens](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens). Simple steps:

1. [Create an account on Github](https://github.com/settings/tokens). You will get something like *acd276d00a9de5a15743b7a0a33e39c0e7b8aed8*. Be sure to make a note as you will not be able to look at it after some time.
2. Use Composer terminal (Git, for example) and enter command:

   `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>`

Where `<oauthtoken>` is your token.

It should be configured now and Composer should now allow you to install.

Comment: Ok, it works, next i am trying to init yii app, using command "php init --env=Development --overwrite=All" for init without console dialog, but i have message: "Do you want to set the parameters for connecting to the database? [Yes|No]". How to init app without db-connection dialog ?

Comment: Depends on which type of Yii2 you're using. If you're using advanced, then set database connection in `environments > dev > common > config > main-local.php` or `config > db.php` if you're using simple type. I don't know if this is exactly what you wanted but once you have connection you shouldn't be asked for DB details.

Comment: Yes, a using advanced type, so i need to set up one more enviroment for bb, right ? It might be helpful, thanks.